# jQuery and php includes for an image slider

Tags: php, jquery, include, sliders

I am trying to use an image slider like anything slider. When I place all the contents on the same file it works without a glitch, but when I separate the code into the header include, footer include and then the file itself it no longer works.

I checked my file paths and all seems to be correct and I run into the same issue when I use other image sliders. Not sure how to resolve the issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"Not sure how to resolve the issue."* Same here. Hard to tell without any code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a developper console  to obtain some debug information (Press 'F12' on chrome or install the firebug extension on Firefox). 

There should be a "Network" tab that shows what requests are made from the page.
 
And a "JS console" that may reveal some JS errors. 
Maybe it will help you understand what is happening. 
Don't hesitate to post results here,  and a link to your page.